# Add step to scenario after initialization in gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm new at scala and also gatling. I'm trying to create some sort of scenarioBuilder executing different steps based on a certain conditions but I have an issue. I don't know if I can add steps to my scenario.
something like that

```
val scn = scenario("scenario")
    for(req <- requestsList.requests)
      if(req.method == "GET")
       scn.exec("do something")
```

It is possible to add steps in loop and also based on condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your request list into a [Feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder) and then use [doSwitch](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/?highlight=switch#doswitch).

Suppose your request are put into a .csv file with two columns:

```
method, endpoint
GET,/api/bar
POST,/api/bar
GET,/api/foo
```

```
val requestFeeder = csv("requests.csv") 

val scn: ScenarioBuilder =
    scenario("Foo Scenario")
      .feed(requestFeeder)
      .doSwitch("${method}")(
        "GET" -> exec(http("Get request")
          .get("${endpoint}")
          .check(status.in(200 to 210))),
        "POST" -> exec(http("Get request")
          .post("${endpoint}")
          .check(status.in(200 to 210))))
```